# What is the meaning of FOR XML PATH(' ')?

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

Whats is the meaning of

```
FOR XML PATH('')?
```

What does it represent. As there is no root node to it.

Comment: Have you read the relevant documentation on MSDN? If so, what particular part do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @MartinSmith Well, the `for xml` documentation in the T-SQL book is a good start :)

Comment: @Luaan - I had a quick glance at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178107.aspx and didn't see anything mentioned but see you have found some.

Comment: If you googled before you asked, you should mention what you found that you didn't understand.   If you didn't, well, shame on you.

Comment: @TabAlleman I was unable to find anything very clearly . That's why asked here. Thanks for your motivating comments though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of confusion about "Root" and "Element". In XML, the root is a single node at the top of the tree.

If we specify FOR XML PATH with nothing following, then we get a set of XML elements called "Row". This is a default name.

```
USE AdventureWorks2016CTP3;
GO

SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName
    FROM Person.Person
    WHERE BusinessEntityID BETWEEN 14500 AND 14502
    FOR XML PATH;
```

[image]

We can specify a different name for the enclosing XML element like this.

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName
    FROM Person.Person
    WHERE BusinessEntityID BETWEEN 14500 AND 14502
    FOR XML PATH('Person');
```

[image]

If we want the XML elements to be enclosed in a top level root element, we can specify it like this.

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName
    FROM Person.Person
    WHERE BusinessEntityID BETWEEN 14500 AND 14502
    FOR XML PATH('Person'),
    ROOT('People');
```

[image]

Specifying an empty string for the element name, causes it to leave out the enclosing XML elements. It seems a very peculiar thing to do. I can't imagine why anyone would want to do that.

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName
    FROM Person.Person
    WHERE BusinessEntityID BETWEEN 14500 AND 14502
    FOR XML PATH('');
```

[image]

However Books Online does say this is the correct behaviour. See Basic Syntax of the FOR XML Clause > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190922.aspx > Arguments > PATH.

> If you provide an empty string (FOR XML PATH ('')), no wrapper element is generated.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: You're welcome! FOR XML is quite complicated, but it makes sense eventually.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx):

> If you specify a zero-length string, the wrapping element is not produced.

(`' '` fails, so I assume you meant an empty string, not a single space).

This has nothing to do with root elements, that's what `root` is for. This is only about the *wrapping* element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was unable to find any thing regarding this hence asked this question here. whats the use of doing this if there is no root node to an XML?

Comment: @NimbleFungus - The use case I see it used for most often is string concatenation in conjunction with the behaviour of un-named columns. e.g. `SELECT (select name + ',' FROM sys.all_columns FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')`

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks a lot Martin.

Comment: @NimbleFungus Again, this has nothing to do with the root node - only with the wrapping elements. In some cases, you don't want to wrap the rows in their own elements - there's an example in the article I linked (Generating a value list using PATH mode).

Comment: @MartinSmith I got your point now :D